# How to disable internet on a PSP?

Tags: psp

I'm not allowed to get a PSP unless my parents can disable the internet, and preferably if there is a password for my parents to use. Is there a parental control panel with internet restrictions? And if not, is there another way to permanently block internet access?

Comment: Is there something wrong with this post that I'm missing?

Comment: It displays absolutely no research, nor effort beforehand.  PSP 2000's have been out for seven years now; there's lots of documentation out on them, so doing a little bit of research is to be expected before asking.

Comment: There are no parental controls, but your parents can block the WiFi Access via the MAC of the PSP (unique adress of the network device, not to be mistaken for IP).

Comment: The could always just super-glue the wireless switch to off. O.o

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you cannot disable Internet connectivity as a whole, you can disable the Internet browser using parental controls.

You'll need to go to **Settings** > **Security Settings**, set a parental controls password (0000 being the default), then enable **Internet Browser Start Control**.

Source: [Playstation Knowledge Center](https://support.us.playstation.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/842/~/parental-controls-for-psp-internet-browser)

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to make comment can't sorry

They could also use OpenDNS to shield all devices in you home as it will handle filtering for them.

Link:
http://www.opendns.com/home-internet-security/parental-controls/opendns-familyshield/